# How to use calculated fields

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have ten list items that work back from one date field. I want to enter a date in the 'Open Date' field in list item 1 and then set a date field in item 2 to be **-7 days** and then set a date field in item 3 to be **-14 days** and then so on for the remainder of the list items. I need this to be displayed in one view so I can't have 10 different calculated columns. Is there a way of doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Calculated Columns do not work across Items you have to use a Workflow to alter the other items.

### But..

*You have to know I have a fetish for Calculated Columns*

#### The million dollar question is how you *order* your 10 items

You can achieve this:

[image]

With a [Calculated Column with some JavaScript](http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How)

```
=IF(ISBLANK( [OpenDate] )
    ,"<img src=/_layouts/images/blank.gif onload=""{"
        &"  var TR=this;while(TR.tagName!='TR'){TR=TR.parentNode}"
        &"  this.nextSibling.innerHTML=(TR.rowIndex-1)*-7;"
        &"}""><button onclick=""{alert(this.innerHTML);}""></button>"
    , [OpenDate]
   )
```

All you need to add [is some JSOM update code](http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create/Changedate)

#### (update #1) Always in for a challenge...

[image]

Can be done with one Calculated Column set to datatype=Number and Formula:

```
=IF(OpenDate,"<span id='od'>"
&TEXT(OpenDate,"mm/dd/yyyy")
&"","<img src=/_layouts/images/blank.gif onload=""{"
&"var TR=this;while(TR.tagName!='TR'){TR=TR.parentNode}"
&"var ID=TR.id.split(',')[1];"
&"var d=document.getElementById('od').innerHTML.split('/');"
&"var newd=new Date( d[2] , d[0]-1 , ~~d[1]+(TR.rowIndex-1) * -3 );"
&"window.updateDate=function(me,setdate){"
&"    var TR=me;while(TR.tagName!='TR'){TR=TR.parentNode}"
&"    var ID=TR.id.split(',')[1];"
&"    var clientContext=new SP.ClientContext.get_current();" 
&"    var list=clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList());" 
&"    var item=list.getItemById( ID );" 
&"    clientContext.load(item);" 
&"    item.set_item('OpenDate',new Date(setdate));" 
&"    item.update();" 
&"    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(" 
&"     Function.createDelegate(this, function(){" 
&"        AJAXRefreshView({currentCtx:ctx,csrAjaxRefresh:true},1);" 
&"     }));"
&"};"
&"this.nextSibling.innerHTML=newd;"
&"}"">"
&"<button style=""width:250px;cursor:pointer;"""
&" onclick=""{event.preventDefault();window.updateDate(this,this.innerHTML);}""></button>")
```

Notes:

- the IMG load triggers the setting of the button label.
- offset days is calculated in the Date function (~~ converts a string to an integer)
- onclick the update function is called, we need to pass which button was called, and I have added the innerHTML as well so the function can be reused.
- The function itself is created for every listitem on the window.. bit dirty.. but works
- inside the function you have to get the TR and ID again... you could do a JavaScript bind() but then need a function array (one for each item)
- you can **not** call update straight away because everything is loading inline and the SharePoint Context does not exist yet. Automation sure is possible but requires more code

Comment: Right ok, thanks for confirming. I found this post that explains how it can be done by workflow: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142475/calculate-date-minus-x-days-in-designer-workflow

Comment: I'd suppose this can be done using JSLink as well. Maybe on OnPostRender() we can loop through the rows and change the td? Not sure about this though. Can you confirm, @DannyEngelman?

Comment: It can be done with any type of coding that can change Items. First question is.. How do you determine the order of those 10 items?

Comment: could you not just use the view to order!!?

Comment: Yes, the whole ordering is done in the View.. With what is up to you.. I used reverse sort on OpenDate and Task Name as second sort. You could also add an extra Order column to force an order.