# Sending email reminders through workflow in document library

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-email

Is it possible to send an email based on specific date field in document library? i.e 30 days before the start of the date, on the date itself and 30 days later.

Any possible solution using workflow?

By setting the `DateColumnName + 0 days` as criteria in retention policy in document library, I can send the email on the date mentioned by triggering the workflow but its not possible to send 30 days before as it wont accept days in negative. is there any other way of achieving the same? I dont want to implement this through timer job please

Comment: checked this - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142475/calculate-date-minus-x-days-in-designer-workflow or http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176704/3-days-before-due-date-email-reminder-workflow ?

Comment: i know of this option of pausing but consider a document library with thousands of document. i dont want to have workflow paused for every item. Also what if they modify the item?

Answer (score 0):

Are you on 2013? Have never done it before, but how about a 2013 site workflow that uses the ability to loop through your documents via http web service and sends the email.They're a pain to set up but might do what you need.

You could limit it to any document within the 60 day timeframe so you don't have to grab thousands of documents, and then you could have it pause for a day. Then you'd only have one workflow that was paused.

Usually I do something like this in powershell and schedule it to run once/day, but I like the idea of a site workflow that could do the same thing.